# Possible: json_encode($data) and shell injection?

Tags: php, shell, security, laravel-4, php-5.4

I have a use case where I need to take a PHP array formatted out of data from an external API, and send it to a command for further processing.

The only plausible option was to json_encode($data) and pass that to CLI, and then json_decode($data, true) on the other end. Knowing the importance of sanitizing data, I used escapeshellarg(json_encode($data)), but that prevented json_decode($data, true) from correctly creating my array back on the other end.

So my question, are there any possible shell injection points if we're strictly sending a string that's been created by the json_encode() function?

```
$cmd = "php {$artisan_path} my:command " . escapeshellarg(json_encode($data)) . " {$user_id} >> {$log_file} 2>&1 & echo $!;";
system($cmd);
```

Comment: Apart from "it doesn't work", we do not know anything about your problem with the command line data transport. Care to elaborate? To answer your question: Assume there are injection points.

Comment: The json string passed as a command line argument was not able to be parsed back to a PHP array with json_decode($data, true). How are there injection points if a json string is enclosed in double quotes and all quotes are escaped by the json_encode function?

Comment: What was the data you tried to send, what was the command created, and what was the decode result? Regarding JSON: Encoding is the worst issue here. JSON is UTF-8, and the shell can be anything. There is a reason `mysqli_real_escape_string` has to know the connection encoding to prevent strange multibyte encodings to not slip unescaped quotes into SQL - this is basically the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

You could base64-encode the encoded JSON (and decode it on the other end). That guarantees to give you a very limited character set (a-zA-Z0-9+/=), none of which is significant for a shell I believe.

It does increase the size of the data (by 1/3), though.

However, passing the data via a pipe is probably a better option, especially if it can be a bit long.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `serialize()` and save the result to a file. Then pass the filename to the command.

A more elaborated (but nice) approach would be to use `proc_open()` instead of `system()`. With `proc_open()` you have full control over the cmd's stdin, stdout, stderr and can pipe the data into the cmd's stdin.